# how to reassing a changed cell value back in a dataframe in r with the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do some work with data for building energy consumption. The data are sufficiently large (about 20 m. lines) and i am using the train and building_metadata dataframes joined in one from the ashrae energy prediction from kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ashrae-energy-prediction/data)

I have created an new variable energy_sqm and i found for example in a certain building an outage i want to correct for. The code is working fine in finding and mutating the variables i want to fix.

But i cannot get how to re-insert it in the original dataframe since tidyverse works by not doing inplace substitution of the values. Thus i need to somehow to put the new values in the df but the <- does not work.

The code that works:

```r
joined %>% 
  filter(building_id == 778, meter == 0, timestamp == ymd_hms("2016-08-24 15:00:00")) %>% 
  mutate(
    meter_reading = joined %>% 
      filter(building_id == 778, meter == 0, timestamp == ymd_hms("2016-08-23 15:00:00")) %>% 
      pull(meter_reading), 
    energy_sqm = joined %>% 
      filter(building_id == 778, meter == 0, timestamp == ymd_hms("2016-08-23 15:00:00")) %>% 
      pull(energy_sqm))
```

and the output is :

```
# A tibble: 1 x 11
  building_id meter timestamp           meter_reading site_id primary_use square_feet year_built
        <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>      <dbl>
1         778     0 2016-08-24 14:00:00          328.       6 Entertainm~      108339         NA
# ... with 3 more variables: floor_count <dbl>, square_meter <dbl>, energy_sqm <dbl>
```

which is what i want with the changes included.

If  i try to reinsert it in the original position which is the

```r
joined %>% 
  filter(building_id == 778, meter == 0, timestamp == ymd_hms("2016-08-24 15:00:00"))
```

with the `<-` operation it does not work.

So how can i reassign such values back in the dataframe? It is not a modification of the whole df which i can easy just reassing it. It is only a filtered row basically that i am changing the values of two variables (energy_meter and energy_sqm) and need to reinsert.

To clarify the basic dataframe looks like

```
A tibble: 8,775 x 11
   building_id meter timestamp           meter_reading site_id
         <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         778     0 2016-01-01 00:00:00          172.       6
 2         778     0 2016-01-01 01:00:00          171.       6
 3         778     0 2016-01-01 02:00:00          171.       6
 4         778     0 2016-01-01 03:00:00          171        6
 5         778     0 2016-01-01 04:00:00          171.       6
 6         778     0 2016-01-01 05:00:00          170.       6
 7         778     0 2016-01-01 06:00:00          174.       6
 8         778     0 2016-01-01 07:00:00          174.       6
 9         778     0 2016-01-01 08:00:00          175.       6
10         778     0 2016-01-01 09:00:00          174.       6
# ... with 8,765 more rows, and 6 more variables: primary_use <chr>,
#   square_feet <dbl>, year_built <dbl>, floor_count <dbl>,
#   square_meter <dbl>, energy_sqm <dbl>
```

and to see the variables i want to change is :

```
 A tibble: 8,775 x 4
   building_id meter timestamp           energy_sqm
         <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                   <dbl>
 1         778     0 2016-01-01 00:00:00     0.0171
 2         778     0 2016-01-01 01:00:00     0.0170
 3         778     0 2016-01-01 02:00:00     0.0170
 4         778     0 2016-01-01 03:00:00     0.0170
 5         778     0 2016-01-01 04:00:00     0.0170
 6         778     0 2016-01-01 05:00:00     0.0169
 7         778     0 2016-01-01 06:00:00     0.0172
 8         778     0 2016-01-01 07:00:00     0.0173
 9         778     0 2016-01-01 08:00:00     0.0174
10         778     0 2016-01-01 09:00:00     0.0173
# ... with 8,765 more rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wil Thank you very much for your suggestion and time. I hadn't seen of that update. It is a lot sorter than the one i am posting, however i could not make rows_update work. It kept through an error "Error: Attempting to update missing rows.". The rows_upsert however with the same configuration worked perfectly in adding another row with the single row dataframe i created with my above code.

Now the solution that worked was a twist of the known

`df %>% mutate(variable_name = replace(variable_name, variable_name == something, replace_value))`.

In order however not flatten the dataframe i put the search inside the mutate like below

```
joined <- joined %>%
  mutate(meter_reading = replace(meter_reading,
        
             # having already found  where the problematic value is a am setting it          
                                 meter_reading == joined %>%  
                                   filter(building_id == 778, 
                                          meter == 0, 
                                          timestamp == ymd_hms("2016-08-24 14:00:00")) %>% 
                                   pull(meter_reading),
          # and replacing the meter_reading value with the same value of the previous day
                                 joined %>% filter(building_id == 778, 
                                                   meter == 0, 
                                                   timestamp == ymd_hms("2016-08-23 14:00:00")) %>% 
                                   pull(meter_reading)))
```

The search part and/or the replacement part can be defined previously to make the code sorter. This way the df gets updated and you can reassign it to the original one with no problem.

I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` 1.0.0 has a [new function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html) `rows_update()` for this purpose. If you assume your original dataset is `basic_df` and your changes are stored in `changes_df` you can use:

```r
library(dplyr)
rows_update(basic_df, changes_df, by = c("build_id", "meter","timestamp"))
```

To assign this back to your original data:

```r
basic_df <- rows_update(basic_dy, changes_df, 
                        by = c("build_id", "meter","timestamp"))
```